# Laravel & Docker: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

This is my folder structure:

```
+-- root-app-dir
|   +-- docker
|   |   +-- Dockerfile
|   |   +-- nginx.conf
|   +-- src // this is where the Laravel app lives
|   +-- docker-compose.yml
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: lykos/laravel
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html/
      - ./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    networks:
      - app-network

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports: 
      - "4306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql

volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: "local"

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: "bridge"
```

This is my nginx.conf

```
server {
  root /var/www/html/public;

  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  server_name _;
  charset utf-8;

  location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
  location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
  }

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d` and try to access the Laravel app through the `htts://localhost:8000` I get this error on my screen

```
UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I have run `sudo chown lykos:lykos -R ./src` from my `root-app-dir` but the issue is still there. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure `lykos:lykos` is being used by your webserver?

Comment: its not on wbserver, its on my local environment. I'm basically trying to set my repositories locally run on docker

Comment: i meant `nginx`, are you sure the process is running as your own user? or a nginx related user?

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: is there a `nginx.conf` somewere?

Comment: I've added the nginx.conf on my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171869/discussion-between-quezler-and-lykos).

Comment: if you running your app using WSL on windows you have to mount your host volumes properly, the issue is described here: https://superuser.com/questions/1323645/unable-to-change-file-permissions-on-ubuntu-bash-for-windows-10
after that it is possible to change permission and laravel will work fine

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are several options, what could be wrong:

1. The `storage` link isn't properly set, you can read about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem), after launching `app` container, you should do `php artisan storage:link` to check whether proper link is there
2. You don't have the proper right for the given folder, from default, `logs` folder should have `www-data` writable rights, you can check that by ssh to machine and the do `ls -l` on files in `/var/www/html/[your laravel app]`, if not, add the proper rights by: `chown -R www-data:www-data *`
3. Also related to file permissions: you can disable SELinux (but only in dev server, never do it on live) by cehcking the status: `sestatus` and then enforcing it to `0` by `setenforce 0` (however on live server, it's better to leave SElinux running and try to disable the problem by `chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t [path to storage folder here]`

Comment: I am having "chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file" when I do chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t

Comment: Note that the container would create `/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log` by `root:root` hence you should run `chown -R www-data:www-data .` on root of the project. Next, the PHP would append logs to the mentioned file obviously by `www-data:www-data`.

Comment: @M.Rostami, can you provide a link to where or how you get this info please, I mean PHP using  user: group

Comment: @dellos PHP processes are usually executed by the web server using a specific user & group. 
The user & group used by PHP to execute scripts can be determined by checking the server's configuration files. For example, in Apache, the user & group are often set in the `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf` file, while in Nginx, they are specified in the `nginx.conf` file or so.
When PHP creates or modifies files (such as log files), it uses the permissions of the user & group under which it is running. In the case of Laravel, the log files are typically stored in the `storage/logs`. (GPT)

Answer (score 87):

if the above does not work when its added to your .env file the following will:

```
sudo chmod o+w ./storage/ -R
```

this will give others permissions without altering user and group permissions.

You should also give access to the www-data user or group.

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R ./storage
```

Comment: This is just a disingenuous way of using `chmod 777`. It's very dangerous, and allows **anyone** to alter the files served to end users.

Comment: @miken32 you probably shouldn't use sail as a production env...

Comment: the file cannot be modified if its served to an end user as these things are controlled via htaccess files or even configuration so that only access point they'd have is through a public directory.

Answer (score 28):

if you are using laravel sail, add following to your .env file

```
WWWGROUP=1000
WWWUSER=1000
```

Answer (score 26):

If you're using Sail on Docker Windows Desktop with WSL2 this issue arises when you start the docker container directly from the dashboard. Instead, start the container within your WSL2 terminal instance i.e

```
sail up -d
```

Comment: On WSL2 the command `./vendor/bin/sail up -d` worked for me

Answer (score 11):

1. With user root:root . You try with command :

   sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
2. With user www-data:www-data . You try with command :

   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage/

   sudo chmod -R 755 storage/
3. If you use Docker . You try with command :

   sudo chown -R nginx:nginx storage/

   sudo chmod -R 755 storage/

Answer (score 5):

Following worked for me, executed both commands in following sequence in WSL2 command line, Hope this case helps someone

1 : Answer given by @nam-sama

```
With user root:root . You try with command :

sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

And 2 : Answer given by @Rob-Mascaro

```
sail up -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to emphasize more on [Toosche's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50553093/10907864). I experienced this issue when trying to deploy a Docker PHP application.

My working directory was `/var/www/html`. And I added commands to create a USER called `docker` in the `Dockerfile`.

And I already had the following commands in my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && sudo chmod 775 -R /var/www/html \
```

And the below commands in my startup script:

```
chmod -R ugo+rw /.composer
chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/html/storage/
chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/storage/
chmod -R 775 /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/
```

After the deployment I get the error below when I try to use the app:

> The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2023-02-01.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied\nThe exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2023-02-01.log\

**Here's how I solved it**:

The container creates `/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log` by `root:root` after it starts up. So I checked the files and folders ownership in the running container and found the below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    515 Feb  2 00:09 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 app
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   1686 Feb  2 00:09 artisan
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 bootstrap
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   2098 Feb  2 00:09 composer.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 312509 Feb  2 00:09 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 726014 Feb  2 00:09 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    473 Feb  2 00:09 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   1202 Feb  2 00:09 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 public
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 resources
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 routes
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    563 Feb  2 00:09 server.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root       4096 Feb  2 00:09 storage
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 tests
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 vendor
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    559 Feb  2 00:09 webpack.mix.js
```

All I had to do to resolve this and remove duplicated commands was to remove the commands above in my `Dockerfile` and startup script, and added only the command below in startup script, which gave the `www-data` user and group permission of all files and folders in the working directory:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data *
```

I also left the command below in my startup script for composer:

```
chmod -R ugo+rw /.composer
```

Afterwhich I built and redeployed the app again. This time I checked the files and folders ownership in the running container and they were fine as below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    515 Feb  2 00:09 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 app
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   1686 Feb  2 00:09 artisan
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 bootstrap
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   2098 Feb  2 00:09 composer.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 312509 Feb  2 00:09 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 726014 Feb  2 00:09 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    473 Feb  2 00:09 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   1202 Feb  2 00:09 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 public
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 resources
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 routes
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    563 Feb  2 00:09 server.php
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 storage
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 tests
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Feb  2 00:09 vendor
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    559 Feb  2 00:09 webpack.mix.js
```

Comment: First suggestion did the trick, I just used `chown -R www-data:www-data .`.

Answer (score 1):

Had that issue on Win10. I have moved L10 files to `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\user1\projects` and when opened http://localhost:8000/ got same error.

Check permissions by running WSL terminal in VScode: `docker container exec -it cnphp  ls -la`
[image: -]
See that all folders and files are owned by xfs, except storage.
Actually storage was owned by xfs but here how I solved it:

1- name your app or php container in `docker-compose.yml` file `container_name: cnphp`

2- run in VScode in WSL-terminal:`docker-compose up -d` and

```
docker container exec -it cnphp  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel/bootstrap/cache
docker container exec -it cnphp  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/laravel/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

After `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` owner remains `www-data` and error gone.

After this manipulations if you will run WSL itself, you will see
[image]
I can not comment this, but you see that that WSL shows that storage owner is set to "82" and in VScode storage is "www-data". So the conclusion - use WSL-Ubuntu terminal in VScode to set correct owner.

Answer (score 0):

Run bellow command from host machine

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage`

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue because I was using sail and the default directory for the logs thinks I am using Apache. I could not find any way of changing the log location to the correct storage folder, so I created a symbolic link instead:

```
ln -s /var/www/html/public/storage /home/<yourfoldername>/storage
```

When I ran my script again, it errored properly, and wrote to laravel.log file in the correct location