# Docker Laravel - could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, docker

Have been trying to fix this error for almost an entire day now and have no idea what is possibly causing this issue.

The error I get is: UnexpectedValueException
The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Below are my docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile and conf.d files.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: /laravelproject
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Nginx
    image: /nginx
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    depends_on:
      - app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apk update && apk add \
    build-base \
    freetype-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# copy config
COPY ./config/php/local.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S www && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S www -G www

USER www

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www

EXPOSE 9000
```

app.conf:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

I have tried many solutions but none of them have worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Install Laravel Sail

Comment: Solved also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77808361/7284577

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is pretty easy indeed.

First of all, remember that **docker runs as root by default** so all the actions taken during the creation of your container are done by the root user.

What is happening is that you are running the command `COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www` after having switched to the newly created **www** user: this user does not have the rights to change the owner of a folder own by root!

Another error is that the user you want to set the folder ownership to is not www-data but the www user you just created.

What you want, in the end, is to switch the order of the 2 commands and change the user from www-data to www, look below:

CHANGE THIS

```
USER www

COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www
```

INTO THIS

```
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

USER www
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, for me worked executing manually the code below:

```
docker exec -it --user=root container-name chmod -R 777 /var/www/storage
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the user inside the docker container is running with the same `uid` and `gid` as the user that owns the files on your host.

You can inspect the container user privileges using

```
docker-compose exec <service-name> ls -la /path/to/app/directory
```

in your example the path is `/var/www/`

and then inspect the user privileges int the host

```
ls -la /path/to/host/mount/point
```

in your example the path is `./`

To test it you can just change the `uid` and `gid` in your `Dockerfile` to be the same as your user on the host and it should work.
To be able to pass in this data through your `docker-compose.yml` you can add `build-args` to your compose file like int the [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args).

You can also review the way that [Laravel Sail](https://github.com/laravel/sail/tree/1.x/runtimes/8.0) does it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem using Docker Desktop with Laravel on Windows 10. I was running into file permission issues. Namely: `file_put_contents(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

Editing the permissions would allow me to use artisan commands to create files, but then prevent me from actually editing the files locally using Visual Studio Code (or vice versa).

A lot of searching didn't yield  helpful results until I found this post about the issue: https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/81#issuecomment-1304499939

The issue could be replicated by **starting the container using the GUI play button in docker desktop**.

The issue can be avoided by starting your container from command line with:

```
    sail up -d
```

The -d flag is optional (to run it in the background). After starting this way via command line (instead of using the Docker Desktop client play button) - the permission issues go away. The primary difference I can find is that if the container is spun up using Docker Desktop, inside the container the

Group:User == 1000:sail.

If the command `sail up -d` is used, inside the container the

Group:User == sail:sail.

You can confirm yourself by starting using both methods, and running `sail root-shell`, then once in the container `ls -ll`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apk update && apk add \
    build-base \
    freetype-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

# copy config
COPY ./config/php/local.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S www && \
    adduser -u 1000 -S www -G www

#USER root

COPY --chown=www:www-data . /var/www

RUN chown -R www:www-data /var/www/storage
RUN chmod -R ug+w /var/www/storage

EXPOSE 9000
```

Login to the container terminal and check the directory and file permissions

```
>ls -al

drw-r--r-- 1 www www-data      0 Apr 25 11:57 storage
-rwxrw-rw- 1 www www-data 34434 Apr 25 12:45 laravel.log
```

Also, php-fpm must be executed by `www-data` user.

```
>top

17 root      20   0  236968   8232   2140 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.3 
18 www-data  20   0  236968   8264   2164 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.3 
19 www-data  20   0  236968   8264   2164 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 php-fpm7.3
```

If this isn't the case then override the /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d directory with www-data.conf file (copy or mount as a volume)

```
[www-data.conf]

user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

Comment: I get this error when trying to build the image:  > [ 8/11] RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S www-data &&     adduser -u 1000 -S www-data -G www-data:
#12 0.302 addgroup: group 'www-data' in use

Comment: It looks like you already have the `www-data` user. I corrected my answer a little, now we create a user `www`, maybe you still need him (delete completely if not) and we set permission www (user)::www-data (group), this should work.

Comment: It runs but I still get the same error with not being able to access laravel.log

Comment: Can you show output of `ls -al /var/www/`, `ls -al /var/www/storage/logs`, `top`?

Answer (score -1):

It work for me

```
docker exec -it <your container name> bash
chmod 777 storage/ -R
```

You can try it

Comment: Setting files to 777 is generally a bad practice because it allows anyone to read, write, and execute the files. A more secure way is to only give the permissions that are absolutely necessary.

In the case of Laravel's storage and bootstrap/cache directories, the web server user (www-data in your case) needs to have write access. (775)