# Laravel and Docker permission issue - can't save files

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu

I already saw the solution from this post: ["https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552970/laravel-docker-the-stream-or-file-var-www-html-storage-logs-laravel-log-co](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552970/laravel-docker-the-stream-or-file-var-www-html-storage-logs-laravel-log-co)

But this solution is not sufficient

The problem is that if I do what is said in the solution, i.e. to run `chown -R www-data:www-data *` inside the Docker container - it also changes the permission on the actual folder in the Ubuntu host, not just the container, because I set this folder in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
php:        
    build:
        context: ./laravel
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: laravel
    volumes:
        - ./laravel:/var/www/html
```

and this is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

and my user in the Ubuntu host is `myuser` so when I run the `chown -R www-data:www-data *`,  `myuser` no longer has permissions on the host, and I can't save files.

So I either get Permission denied on the `localhost` URL (as seen in the other post), or I get Permission Denied to save files on VS Code on my Ubuntu host! (I am using WSL2, that's why I can use VS Code)

To sum it up:

1. To be able to save files on my mounted volume, I have to save it as the Ubuntu user, i.e.  `myuser` so I have to run `sudo chown -R myuser ~/myproject`
2. But because certain files in Laravel expects writable permission by `www-data`, I can't get to my website at `localhost` - as seen in the post above.
3. If I change the permissions in the Docker container using `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/`, I lose `myuser` permissions in the host and can't save files again, and vice versa.

Comment: What is the base image for your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: `php-fpm`, edited the post as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `docker-compose.yml` file, add the `user: <uid>:<gid>`

```yaml
php:        
    build:
        context: ./laravel
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: laravel
    user: "1000:1000" #type the "id" command in your terminal and look for uid and gid if you don't know what they are
    volumes:
        - ./laravel:/var/www/html
```

This way, php-fpm will be executed as a user with these identifiers:

- when you save a file from your host (with `myuser`), it will have the same identifiers as php-fpm
- when php write a file, it will be written with the same identifiers too

Comment: Thank you! What exactly is the issue then? Some posts say Laravel expects `www-data` writable permissions on this `laravel.log` file, and some posts don't mention it. And with your solution, I don't even set the user to `www-data`, so how can it work, if it expects `www-data`?

Comment: Laravel doesn't "need" the user to be `www-data`, it just needs the user who runs php-fpm to have read and write perm. on the files of your project. The easiest way to solve issue is then to set your project user to `www-data` since it is the default user of php-fpm. However, this approach has some cons, and you encountered one of them. In a dev env, using the `user` option as we did here is perfectly fine. Quick note, if you ssh into the container, the user will be "I have no name!". It is ok, you can ignore that. This is because there is no actual user with the id you provided.

Comment: Thank you! So you mean that setting the project user to `www-data` in the container is probably for production where the container is not touched, and the project files are copied to it rather than symlinked?

Comment: Yes that's the idea :)

Comment: You helped me many times already, you are a real expert, thank you!

Comment: Oh you are the guy from the other day with the Nextjs app, I remember now :p You know there is no magic, I also had a hard time with all these (many many many) little traps. I wish you good luck in your docker journey.

Comment: Yes! Thank you again, now I have a properly running dev environment using 4 Docker containers with nginx, mysql, laravel as api and nextjs as frontend