# Laravel Sail command does not run in WSL2

Tags: laravel, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-sail

I set up an app using Laravel Sail, and hosted it in my **C:Users/User/my_app** folder, however API endpoints were terribly slow (around **7s** to respond).

I decided to move my application to the WSL filesystem. I copied my_app folder to **\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home** folder. However, when I type **./vendor/bin/sail up** command nothing happens. No error message, no "command not found message", nothing.

I tried changing **home/my_app** permissions as well as **vendor/bin/sail** permissions but it has not helped me. I have no idea how to solve this problem as I am not receiving any message from the console.

Comment: Sail basically uses docker-compose. Verify that you have docker-compose available. If you have docker compose try `docker-compose up` and check any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the issue with copying the files from Windows to WSL using cp command run from WSL console (**cp /mnt/c/users/.....** ). 
However I stubmled upon this error [Laravel & Docker: The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552970/laravel-docker-the-stream-or-file-var-www-html-storage-logs-laravel-log-co) which I solved using the answers from this github thread https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel/issues/49. 
Now my endpoint response times are usually under 100ms.

Comment: Please read this answer to solve the permission issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552970/laravel-docker-the-stream-or-file-var-www-html-storage-logs-laravel-log-co/68904763#68904763