# permission denied on laravel.log file laravel 9 using Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker-compose, dockerfile

I installed laravel using composer inside of my docker container, however, i get this error when i try to access the index page

```
The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log:
```

I am using laravel 9, i have tried all possible solution i could find and it doesn't work.
I run on windows 10.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0.2-fpm

# Install dependencies for the operating system software
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    zip \
    unzip 

# Install extensions for php
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

# Install composer (php package manager)
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www
```

I have adding the below code to my Dockerfile

```
# Assign permissions of the working directory to the www-data user
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
    /var/www/storage \
    /var/www/bootstrap/cache
```

but when  try to build the image again with the code in it, i get an error message saying

> directory doesn't exist

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: jaynesis-php
    restart: always
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: jaynesis-nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ../src:/var/www
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  mysql:
    container_name: jaynesis-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - ./storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Comment: Solved also here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77808361/7284577

Answer (score 3):

Give this a go, it might work...

```
docker exec -it jaynesis-php bash
chmod 755 storage/ -R
```

This makes the storage directory a little more writeable.

Comment: i got this error message `chmod: cannot access 'storage/': No such file or directory`

Comment: Could you try `ls -la` after the docker exec command and post the output here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an error: "The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log:"

Delete this laravel.log file.

Comment: the file never even came with it